# RubyMonk 8.2 Modules as Namespace

Tags: ruby

Overall I am having trouble understanding some concepts in Ruby, Modules being one of them.

I am on the final step in RubyMonk 8.2: Modules as Namespace and I am very lost. What should I do? My plan was to just get the solution and reverse engineer it, but there is no solution button so I am stuck :(

The instructions go as follows:

If you prepend a constant with :: without a parent, the scoping happens on the topmost level. In this exercise, change push to return 10 as per A = 10 in the topmost level, outside the Kata module.

The code already filled in is:

```
module Kata
  A = 5

  module Dojo
    B = 9
    A = 7

    class ScopeIn
      def push
       A
      end
    end
  end
end
A = 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want this:

```
module Kata
  A = 5  
  module Dojo
    B = 9
    A = 7

    class ScopeIn
      def push
       ::A # change this line from A to ::A, meaning ::A will refer to the top-level namespaced A which is defined outside the Kata module (A = 10)
      end
    end
  end
end

A = 10
p Kata::Dojo::ScopeIn.new.push
# => 10
```

If you prepend a constant with `::` without a parent, the scoping happens on the topmost level. In this example, `push` will return `10` since `A = 10` is in the topmost level, outside the Kata module.

Comment: DJBrandoK, let me know if that solves your problem and also if you have any follow-up question. Thanks.

Comment: If it solved your problem, then consider accepting the answer (tick the check mark). To know more about how accepting answers work, please see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sounds good. I accepted the answer. This is my first post on Stackoverflow so I'm still learning <('.')>. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are most welcome and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

```
module Kata
  A = 5
  module Dojo
    A = 7
    class ScopeIn
      def push0
        A
      end
      def push1
        Kata::Dojo::A
      end
      def push2
        Kata::A 
      end
      def push3
        ::A
      end
    end
  end
end
A = 10

scope = Kata::Dojo::ScopeIn.new #=> #<Kata::Dojo::ScopeIn:0x007fe63c8381d0> 

scope.push0 #=>  7 
scope.push1 #=>  7
scope.push2 #=>  5 
scope.push3 #=> 10
```

Comment: I ended up successfully using the second response, but thank you for the help as well!